# Firebase Firestore rules not working by accessing a sub element in document

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

So for example - the following will fail: `request.auth.uid == resource.data.creator.id`

My collection is Tasks/{taskId}
Where task contains:

```
{
  "Title",
  // Creator is An object which contains the user who created it:
  "Creator": {
    "email",
    "id"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Is this about the rules? Structure? Both?

Comment: maybe this is failing because the rules are case sensitive!